# For function overriding, why can visibility be made less restrictive, but mutability only more restrictive?

Tags: solidity, inheritance, function-override

From the solidity docs:

**Function Overriding**

> Base functions can be overridden by inheriting contracts to change
> their behavior if they are marked as virtual. The overriding function
> must then use the override keyword in the function header. The
> overriding function may only change the visibility of the overridden
> function from external to public. The mutability may be changed to a
> more strict one following the order: nonpayable can be overridden by
> view and pure. view can be overridden by pure. payable is an exception
> and cannot be changed to any other mutability.

Why can external functions be changed to public? Wouldn't that make the function callable internally? Why can you make visibility less strict in a function but mutability only more strict?